# How to draw pairs of correlation before and after the crisis using DCC GARCH

Tags: r, correlation, data-visualization, multivariate-analysis, garch

I am using DCC GARCH to show a movement correlations across variables before and after crisis. I want to draw the correlation graph between two variables after estimating model but I have not found the code, I only saw the prediction using:
predict H*, variance then generate the correlations, and finally tsline

Can you help me with this problem, the results I want to have similar to this image. Thank you very much and I appreciate it
[image]

Comment: Looks like this is purely a programming question. If so, it is off topic. Otherwise, please clarify what the statistical aspect of the question is.